# Two similarly syntaxed menus - the one in footer works; the one in the header does not

Tags: hyperlink, navigation, nav

I am learning to make menus. In a tutorial I learned to make a mobile-friendly menu (http://designshack.net/articles/css/responsive-slide-down-navigation). The page I created is at http://nspowers.org/ask/why-menu and uses lists for the links.

The links in the footer work. However, links with identical syntax in the top menu do not link.

Here is the structure of the working footer navigation:

```
<footer id="hfooter">
  <div class="footer_nav">
     <nav>
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="#">Home</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="./work.html">Work</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="./about.html">About</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="./contact.html">Contact</a> </li>
        </ul>
     </nav>
   </div>
          <div class="copyright">&copy</div>
</footer>
```

This is the structure of the top navigation that is not working:

```
    <header id="topnav">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="./work.html">WORK</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="./about.html">ABOUT</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="./contact.html">CONTACT</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <a href="#" id="navbtn">Nav Menu</a>        
    <h1><a href="./index.html">This is the 'home' page</a></h1>
    </header><!-- @end #topnav -->
```

The css is here: http://nspowers.org/ask/why-menu/styles.css.

I would like to learn what other variables may affect successful linking other than the syntax of the links I've looked at in tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

1) First, the menu.js from file has the following in the third section:

```
$('#topnav nav a,#topnav h1 a,#btmnav nav a').on('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault(); // stop all hash(#) anchor links from loading
});
```

Thank you to http://disqus.com/ashearlam, this doesn't need to be there. Delete it. It was supposed to stop the menu from linking away within a mobile view. However, it works fine without it. The working menu.js is as follows:

```
$(function(){
var nb = $('#navbtn');
var n = $('#topnav nav');

$(window).on('resize', function(){

if($(this).width() < 570 && n.hasClass('keep-nav-closed')) {
  // if the nav menu and nav button are both visible,
  // then the responsive nav transitioned from open to non-responsive, then back again.
  // re-hide the nav menu and remove the hidden class
  $('#topnav nav').hide().removeAttr('class');
}
if(nb.is(':hidden') && n.is(':hidden') && $(window).width() > 569) {
  // if the navigation menu and nav button are both hidden,
  // then the responsive nav is closed and the window resized larger than 560px.
  // just display the nav menu which will auto-hide at <560px width.
  $('#topnav nav').show().addClass('keep-nav-closed');
  }
}); 

$('#navbtn').on('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$("#topnav nav").slideToggle(350);
});

});
```

2) The webpage was missing a mobile meta viewport, so the website was not being scaled down to a mobile view when viewed on a mobile device. Adding the meta,

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

resolves this issue.

A working version can be found here: http://nspowers.org/ask/menu-solved